# SSRS one dataset with summary at top and details below

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS and building `.rdl`. My dataset has the data in the format below:

```
PersonId|Name  |City
-------------------------------
1       |Elaine|Toronto
2       |George|Toronto
3       |Jerry |New York
4       |Newman|New York
5       |Kramer|New York
6       |Suzie |New Jersey
```

I need the report to look like this with each city on a separate page:

Page 1:

```
City: Toronto

PersonId|Name  
-------------------------------
1       |Elaine
2       |George
```

Page 2:

```
City: New York

PersonId|Name  
-------------------------------
3       |Jerry
4       |Newman
5       |Kramer
```

Page 3:

```
City: New Jersey

PersonId|Name  
-------------------------------
6       |Suzie
```

I have no problem with the query to get data but I need help on how to format it to look like the above. I have tried grouping but it prints all the cities and after it prints all the records.

Is this possible? And what is this type of report called (if it has some specific name)?

Comment: You don't need any special, just a table with a rowgroup that groups on City, then on the row group properties, set page break as `between`. If you can;t get it working, let me know and I'll post a an example.

Comment: @AlanSchofield But when I do that it adds a column to the left of the rows and puts the city in it. So it it will be `New York` with three rows on the right.

Comment: Just delete the new column. You may be prompted to delete the group too. If you are prompted choose 'delete columns only'. Then add a text box above your table and set its value to your City field.